# How to continue SKAction while app is inactive

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am working on a SKScene app and I have one SKAction in my app after setting something. But after I close the app and make it in the background which means it is inactive, SKAction stops. So I want to know how to make SKAction still work after I close it with it being inactive. Thank you so much!

Comment: not possible, skview is paused while in background

Answer (score 0):

As LearnCocos2D said, you cannot run SKAction when the app is in background.

However if you need to simulate the game continues to run even when in background you can follow this approach:

1. when the app is going to background save the current time
2. when the app is resumed calculate the amount of time **delta** is has been in background
3. manually change your game state according to the **delta** value. Of course depending on the complexity of your game this may not be feasible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give me more details about doing so? Probably give me some codes? I am a little confused.

Comment: A super easy example (your scenario will probably be more complex). Let's say you have an SKAction that moves a sprite A from the top of the screen to the bottom. The action requires 3 minutes to move the sprite. The action starts and after 1 minutes the app goes to background. (here you save current time 23:08)...

Comment: After another minute the app is resumed. Here you get the current time 23:09 and calculate the app has been in background for 1 minute. This means the sprite A should have done a third of its travel from top to bottom. You stop the current action. Move the sprite for a third. Create a new action to move it for the last third of the screen. Hope this is clear.

Comment: And yes, I know it sounds crazy for a game :D

Comment: but how to know the time after the SKAction is created and it is being conducted. In your case, the first one minute.